# Spring Boot - Angular 5 Integration on WebLogic

Tags: spring-boot, weblogic12c

I have created an integrated war for my spring boot and angular 5 application by copying dist folder into the path - WEB-INF/classes/static folder of my war.
When deploying over WebLogic 12c server, I am unable to access my Angular pages.

The structure of war :

[WAR structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34Utc.png)

[classes folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BYyG.png)

When i try to access my application through url: 
1. http://localhost:7001/capmarketai/index.html, the output is:

Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Wed Feb 13 19:58:03 IST 2019
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available

Could anyone please help. I am able to access the services on my Spring boot app but no Angular pages are accessible.

TIA,
SS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with the webLogic installation. Re-installed Weblogic and redployed my app. It is working fine now.